# Bezout identity on polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation, chinese-remainder-theorem

**Question:**

After proving that it exists, find $f(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$ of degree at most 2 such that $$f(x)\equiv2 \text{ mod }x+1\ \text{and }\ f(x)\equiv x+1\text{ mod }x^2+1$$

**My attempt:**

Since $(x+1)$ and $(x^2+1)$ are coprime ideals of $\Bbb Q[x]$ by the Chinese reminder theorem $$\Bbb Q[x]/(x+1)\times\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)\cong\Bbb Q[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$$ and there is a unique $f(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$ that satisfies the property.

To find it let's first ovserve that $${1\over2}(x^2+1)+[-{1\over2}(x-1)](x+1)=1$$

By a theorem the polynomial $f(x)$ should be

$-{1\over2}(x-1)(x+1)^2+{1\over2}(x^2+1)\cdot2\\=-{1\over2}(x^3+x^2-x-1)+x^2+1\text{ mod } (x^3+x^2+x+1)\\=-{1\over2}(-2x-2)+x^2+1\\=x^2-x$

And I find that $x^2-x\equiv 2$ mod $x+1$ but $x^2-x\equiv -x-1$ mod $x^2+1$ instead of $x^2-x\equiv x+1$ mod $x^2+1$ Or is that ok?

$(x+1)(x-2)+2=x^2-x\ $ $\ (x^2+1)-x-1=x^2-x$

Comment: $-\frac{1}{2}(-2)x=x$, and $-\frac{1}{2}(-2)+1=2$.

Comment: But then it doen't work for $x^2+1$

Comment: Another approach would be to let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $f(-1)=2$, $f(i)=i+1$, $f(-i)=1-i$, and solve the system of three linear equations in the three unknowns $a,b,c$.

Comment: Where did you derive those equetions from?

Comment: There is no "but then". You don't get the result you want because you haven't computed it properly. $-\frac{1}{2}(-2x-2)+x^2+1=x^2\mathbf{+x}+\mathbf{2}$. This is $\equiv x+1\pmod{x^2+1}$ and $\equiv 2\pmod{x+1}$.

Comment: $f(x)=(x+1)g(x)+2=(x^2+1)h(x)+x+1$; now let $x=-1$, then $x=i$, and finally $x=-i$.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a **ring** isomorphism

$$f:\Bbb Q[x]/(x+1)\times\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)\to\Bbb Q[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$$

f(a,b)=au+bv where $u = f(1,0)$ and $v = f(0,1)$.

If $u=f(1,0)$, then $u \equiv 1 \pmod{x+1}$ and
$u \equiv 0 \pmod{x^2+1}$

Note that
\begin{align}
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod{x+1} \\ 
   x^2 &\equiv -x \pmod{x+1} \\ 
       &\equiv 1 \pmod{x+1} \\
   x^2+1 &\equiv 2 \pmod{x+1} \\
   \dfrac 12 (x^2+1) &\equiv 1 \pmod{x+1}
\end{align}

So $u = \dfrac 12 (x^2+1)$

If $v=f(0,1)$, then $v \equiv 0 \pmod{x+1}$ and
$v \equiv 1 \pmod{x^2+1}$

Note that
\begin{align}
   x+1 &\equiv x+1 \pmod{x^2+1} \\ 
   (x+1)^2 &\equiv x^2+2x+1 \pmod{x^2+1} \\ 
       &\equiv 2x \pmod{x^2+1} \\
   (x+1)^3 &\equiv 2x^2+2x \pmod{x^2+1} \\
           &\equiv 2x^2+2x-2(x^2+1) \pmod{x^2+1} \\
           &\equiv 2x-2 \pmod{x^2+1} \\
   (x+1)^2 - (x+1)^3 &\equiv 2 \pmod{x^2+1} \\ 
   \dfrac 12((x+1)^2 - (x+1)^3) &\equiv 1 \pmod{x^2+1} \\ 
   -\dfrac 12(x + 2 x^2 + x^3) &\equiv 1 \pmod{x^2+1} \\ 
\end{align}

So $v = -\dfrac 12(x^3 + 2x^2 + x)$

---

\begin{align}
   f(2,x+1) &\equiv 2(\dfrac 12 (x^2+1)) 
       + (x+1)(-\dfrac 12(x^3 + 2x^2 + x))
       \pmod{x^3+x^2+x+1} \\
   f(2,x+1) &\equiv -\dfrac 12 x^4 
                - \dfrac 32 x^3 
                - \dfrac 12 x^2 
                - \dfrac 12 x + 1 \pmod{x^3+x^2+x+1}
\end{align}

Note that 
\begin{align}
   x^4 &\equiv x^4 \pmod{x^3+x^2+x+1} \\
   x^4 &\equiv x^4 - x(x^3+x^2+x+1) \pmod{x^3+x^2+x+1} \\
   x^4 &\equiv -x^3-x^2-x \pmod{x^3+x^2+x+1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   f(2,x+1) &\equiv -\dfrac 12 x^4 
                - \dfrac 32 x^3 
                - \dfrac 12 x^2 
                - \dfrac 12 x + 1 \pmod{x^3+x^2+x+1} \\
       &\equiv -\dfrac 12 (-x^3-x^2-x) 
                - \dfrac 32 x^3 
                - \dfrac 12 x^2 
                - \dfrac 12 x + 1 \pmod{x^3+x^2+x+1} \\
      &\equiv 1-x^3 \pmod{x^3+x^2+x+1}
\end{align}

CHECK:

$1 - x^3 = (-x^2 + x - 1)(x + 1) + 2$

$1 - x^3 = -x(x^2 + 1) + x + 1$